# How to get the last days from a selected date?

Tags: php, laravel, date

**How to get the last days from a selected date?**
Given:

```
$declation_date  = "2019-01-01"
$lastDays     = date('Y-m-t',$declation_date);
```

> I want to display
>   $lastDays = 31;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert the date string to a unix timestamp using the [strtotime() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), then use the [date() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert that timestamp to a readable format, as you only want to get the last day of the month, just put the "t" format as it will display the total days of the month.

```
$declation_date = "2019-01-01";
echo date('t', strtotime($declation_date)); // outputs 31
```